# pandas groupby multiple columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I was try to get a average columns for all the std columns

[image]

I want to add one more column to calculate the average value from Std_4-Std_10 values. 
Not sure should I use groupby or pivot. 
Thanks

Comment: Please post dataframes as text, not as images

Comment: And you shouldn't need either, just use `df.iloc[:, 1:].mean(1)`

Comment: Thank you it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.filter(like='Std').mean(1)
```

To add it back into your dataframe, use:

```
df['mean_Std'] = df.filter(like='Std').mean(1)
```